# How Do I open a gresource file

Tags: 14.04, themes

I am attempting to edit the adwaita theme, the only way to do this is to open the `gtk.gresource` file.

`gedit` will not open the file, `geany` will not open the file.

How do I open the file so I can edit `gtk.css`?

Comment: I recently discovered this: https://github.com/JohnOberhauser/GResourceScripts Works perfectly to me...

Answer (score 14):

since some time, GTK-3 theme CSS files are precompiled into a binary format (`*.gresource`) and installed as a bundle. There is a helper program called **gresource** to deal with these files

- usually, it is installed alongside with the library GLib
- thus it should be in the package `libglib2.0-bin`
- and since this package is usually already installed, you'll find it in your `/usr/bin` and get more documentation by invoking `man gresource`

In short

- to list the contents of a `*.gresource` file:

  ```
   gresource list gtk.gresource
  ```
- to extract a specific resource from it:

  ```
   gresource extract gtk.gresource /org/gnome/adwaita/gtk-main.css
  ```

Basically, this allows you to get the contents of the original Theme extracted. You could make a conventional Theme (with discrete CSS files) from the extracted resources. The key point to note for this is that you have to change the entry point in the top level `gtk-3.0/gtk.css` file within your theme. In binary themes, you'll find there a URL reference

```
@import url("resource:///org/gnome/THEMENAME/gtk-main.css");
```

You need to change this reference to point to your locally installed files

```
@import url("gtk-main.css");
```

---

If you want to compile a new binary bundle from a theme you edited in discrete CSS files, see this [Blog post from 2012 by Satyajit Sahoo](https://web.archive.org/web/20170501023949/https://wibblystuff.blogspot.com/2012/06/building-binary-for-gtk3-theme.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ file gtk.*
gtk.css:       ASCII text
gtk.gresource: GVariant Database file, version 0
```

So the answer is: you do not. It is software (see [gvariant](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/docs/latest/glib/glib-GVariant.html#GVariant)).

> so I can edit the gtk.css

That one is an ASCII file so editable with gEdit.

Comment: Thanks Rinzwind. But I don't understand what you wrote in code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the folowing  script to recursively extract all files from gresource (save it to `~/bin/gextract.sh` and make it executable):

```
#!/bin/bash

# recursively extract gresource

for file in "$@"; do
    gresource list "$file" | while read i; do
        filepath="${i#/}"
        dirpath="${filepath%/*}"
        mkdir -p "$dirpath"
        cd "$dirpath"
            gresource extract "$file" "$i" > "${i##*/}"
        cd - >/dev/null
    done
done
```

Usage:

```
gextract.sh gtk.gresource
```

it will create a directory tree with files (it's like unpack an archive)