# Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 LTS reduce icon size

Tags: gnome, 16.04, gnome-classic

I have installed Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 LTS

- On Intel® Desktop Board DH55TC
- With Intel® Core™ i3 CPU 540 @ 3.07GHz
- 500 GB SATA hard drive
- Connected to 42" LG TV with HDMI cable
- TP-Link 300 MB USB wireless LAN
- Wireless keyboard & mouse

Everything is fine and smoothly. But I want to reduce the icon size in "Show Application" grid.

Middle Part in below Screen
[image]

How can I do it !!

Comment: What is "Show Application"? Is it Unity Dash?

Comment: @NgocThangPham I added screen. In that middle part icons

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The themes are now in binary files [gresource](https://askubuntu.com/questions/572511/how-do-i-open-a-gresource-file/654819), you would need to either unpack the gresource file, make your change and put it back together.

`mkdir ~/shell-theme` and create `extractgst.sh` inside this directory and paste the following to that file.

```sh
#! /bin/sh

workdir="${HOME}/shell-theme"
gst="/usr/share/gnome-shell/gnome-shell-theme.gresource"
mkdir theme

for r in `gresource list $gst`; do
  gresource extract $gst $r >$workdir${r/#\/org\/gnome\/shell/}
done
```

Execute above script you will get all source file from `gnome-shell-theme.gresource`.

Use your editor and edit `gnome-shell.css` file.

And fix values as the following(You can choose other values).

```
.icon-grid {
    spacing: 18px;                       /* was 36px */
    -shell-grid-item-size: 35px;         /* was 70px */
}

.all-app .icon-grid {
    -shell-grid-item-size: 59px;         /* was 118px */
}

.all-app .overview-icon {
    icon-size: 48px;                     /* was 96px */
}
```

Now you have to build new `gnome-shell-theme.gresource`

Download [gnome-shell-theme.gresource.xml](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-shell/blob/master/data/gnome-shell-theme.gresource.xml) from github and put it into your `~/shell-theme/theme` directory

```
cd ./theme
glib-compile-resources gnome-shell-theme.gresource.xml
```

Then copy the resulting `gnome-shell-theme.gresource` file to the `/usr/share/gnome-shell` directory.

Detail: [HERE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66801/how-to-reduce-the-size-of-all-gnome-shell-icons) and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/3sp3s1/how_to_change_the_appearance_height_fonts/) and [bbs.archlinux.org](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1526363#p1526363)

Comment: I have seen this answer already and it is useless for me as in my system I don't have **gnome-shell.css** file

Comment: which version of GNOME do you use?

Comment: I have installed Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 LTS and it have GNOME Shell 3.18

Comment: Check this directory: `/usr/share/gnome-shell/gnome-shell-theme.gresource`. Does it exist?

Comment: Yes I have that file

Comment: I edited my answer. Can you have a look

Comment: how to pack it back !! You are just showing unpack

Comment: I edited the answer and add how to compile the gresource file. You should have a look at Detail. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

For those wanting to reduce desktop and nautilus icons here's what you need to do, at least for Ubuntu Gnome 17.04:

**Going below 48px requires changing the Nautilus source code and recompiling.** (Yes, they hard-coded icons sizes.)

**** INSTRUCTIONS FOR NAUTILUS 3.20.4 ON UBUNTU-GNOME 17.04 ****

1. Install the following dependencies:

   ```
   sudo apt install libgd-dev autotools-dev libexif-dev libexempi-dev libselinux1-dev libtracker-sparql-1.0-dev libext-dev libxml2-dev libgnome-desktop-3-dev
   ```

   Each one installs a bunch of other stuff, so hopefully I've given you the correct parent package name. I apologize for not recalling with 100% accuracy exactly what I installed, but this looks fairly correct to me immediately after my install. (Notify me if I'm inaccurate anywhere.)
2. Download from the [Nautilus snapshots website](https://download.gnome.org/sources/nautilus/) the version of Nautilus that you are currently using. To find that out, run "nautilus --version" from the terminal. After downloading the archive, unzip it to whatever directory you want to work from.
3. From within the unzipped package, open the file "nautilus-icon-info.h". Within the first several lines you will see various sizes designated for the particular scroll-setting options. For instance, within the file for version 3.20.4 the icon sizes start on line 36. Change each of those levels to whatever you want to use so that you can make the icons much smaller (or larger).
4. After editing and saving the file, it's time to configure, compile, and install. Run the following commands from the terminal from within the base directory of the version of nautilus that you have downloaded and unzipped. Make sure that you are within the base of the folder structure of the nautilus directories!

   ```
   ./configure  
   make  
   sudo make install
   ```

   This can be run altogether with the command `./configure && make && make install`.

   If the `./configure` command fails it's because you are missing some other dependencies. I apologize if my list of dependencies above was incomplete. Google (or whatever search engine you want) to find what package it is that you need. You can use Synaptic to search for what you need if you're unsure even after Googling.
5. Once installed, I suggest a reboot just to make sure that every single thing is reloaded properly. You can now tweak your icon sizes as you wish.

Comment: There's no ./configure in Nautilus sources. Meson or jhbuild are used now, via: http://kevlopez.com/blog/compiling-nautilus-with-meson/ . It seems this though is the way to build GNOME apps: https://wiki.gnome.org/Newcomers/BuildProject