# 17.10 - how to decrease icons size in Gnome shell applications dash?

Tags: icons, 17.10, gnome-shell, activities-overview

Yet another question about how to decrease icons size in applications dash, now for 17.10.

I tried:

In /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com/dash.js line 160 :

```
const baseIconSizes = [16, 22, 24]; //, 32, 48, 64, 96, 128];
```

In /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/gnome-shell.css line 1211 :

```
icon-size: 32px; } // instead of 96px
```

I don't have a "iconGrid.js" file.
I didn't see this parameter in Gnome Tweak tool.

Does someone has done it on 17.10 ?

Comment: It is possible from the Dock settings in the Overall settings menu via GUI.

Comment: @Rooney : This changes the dock icons size. I would like to change applications dash icons size (when I click on the applications button at the bottom of the dock)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 LTS reduce icon size](https://askubuntu.com/questions/785620/ubuntu-gnome-16-04-lts-reduce-icon-size)