# How can I change the font of the top bar without changing the shell theme?

Tags: themes, fonts, gnome-shell, top-bar

I am using Ubuntu GNOME 17.04. I want to change the font of the GNOME top bar from the default font by Adapta to Fira Sans. I already have all the fonts, I just want to change the font of the top bar so it doesn't look out of place compared to everything else.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You may create a custom css override in your home directory and load it from there (otherwise if you make any change in the theme's style sheet, any update of the theme will most probably overwrite it).

First you should know where the *Adapta* theme is located. If you have installed it from a `.deb` package or a PPA it should be located at `/usr/share/themes/Adapta` and there should be a `gnome-shell.css` file in `/usr/share/themes/Adapta/gnome-shell/`.

Now follow the steps below.

1. Create a directory, say `MyTheme` either in `~/.themes` or in `~/.local/share/themes`. (You may create `~/.themes` or `~/.local/share/themes` if they don't exist.)
2. Create another directory inside `MyTheme` called `gnome-shell`.
3. Create an empty document in this `gnome-shell` directory and name it `gnome-shell.css`.
4. Open this `gnome-shell.css` in a text editor and add the following lines

   ```
   @import url("/usr/share/themes/Adapta/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css");  

   stage {
       font-family: FONT_NAME, Sans-Serif;
       font-size: 14pt;
   }
   ```

Change `FONT_NAME` to a font of your choice (also you may change the font size) and save the file.

5. Open *GNOME Tweak Tools* and activate the **User themes** extension.
   (If the extension is not installed, you may install it from [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/19/user-themes/).)
6. Go to **Appearance** section of Tweak Tools and click on the drop-down box next to "*Shell theme*". **MyTheme** should appear in the drop-down list. Select it.
7. Restart GNOME shell by typing <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd> then <kbd>R</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> (works in an Xorg session, in Wayland logout and login again).

Comment: `font-size` did not change the font size on my computer.

Comment: This method also doesn't work for themes that use `gresource` files (i.e., Yaru), so you should mention that it won't work in those cases.

Comment: @Melab You can easily deal with them either by directly importing the resource from a `.gresource` file into your custom `.css` file or by manually extracting the required resources from the `.gresource` file. Feel free to post a new answer addressing these.

Comment: Please explain you import a `.gresource`.

Comment: I have. Nothing turned up that explicitly mentioned how to import a `.gresource` file in a custom user theme CSS file.

Comment: @Melab https://askubuntu.com/questions/572511/how-do-i-open-a-gresource-file

Comment: Nope. That talks about extracting `.gresource` files.

Comment: @Melab No, it's not *just* that. Please read the full answer thoroughly, especially the end part (*hint*: you just need to use `@import url("resource://VIRTUAL-PATH");` instead of `@import url("ACTUAL-PATH");` as described here). If you still don't understand how to use that answer in your specific case, consider posting a new question asking for more detailed explanations with the link to that answer as a reference.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the answer to my question! The most effective way to change the font of the top bar is to change the font families in the `gnome-shell.css` file.

To do this, first use

```
sudo -H nautilus
```

to open a root version of Nautilus.

You will then want to navigate to `/usr/share/themes/"THEME_NAME"/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css/`. 
Open the file and where it says something like

```
stage { font-size: 10pt; font-family: Roboto, Cantarell, Sans-Serif; font-weight: 400; color: #263238; }
```

change the first font to the name of your font. The result should be something like

```
stage { font-size: 10pt; font-family: Fira Sans, Cantarell, Sans-Serif; font-weight: 400; color: #263238; }
```

if you changed the font to Fira Sans.

Restart the shell using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and then type `r`.

Doing this makes the themes you want have the fonts you want instead of changing to Adwaita.

Note: Updates to GTK Themes can mess up this configuration, so pomsky's answer has been marked as the best.

Comment: I made the change to my answer to work with the Adapta theme. By the way you should [never start a graphical application like Nautilus or gedit with normal sudo](https://askubuntu.com/q/270006/). As an alternative you may use `nano` to edit text in the command line or run `sudo -H gedit`, `sudo -H nautilus` etc.

Answer (score 1):

In **Ubuntu 19.10** the `gnome-shell.css` location is:

**/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/Yaru/gnome-shell.css**

Edit `gnome-shell.css` as administrator. Then search for

```
stage {
  font-family:
```

Just add your desired font-family name. For example:

```
stage {
  font-family: Fira Sans, Cantarell, Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 10pt;
  color: #3D3D3D; }
```

Done. Save it and log-out and log-in again.

Comment: No need to logout & login again. Just Alt+F2, type `r` then enter. This will reload gnome-shell.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here, changing gnome-shell.css files is no longer needed thanks to the changes provided by GNOME 3.36. Changing the interface font normally now changes the font globally. (everything including the GNOME menu, status bar, etc.)