# Ubuntu 18.04: How to customize the font face and size in Dash to panel extension?

Tags: customization, gnome-panel, ubuntu-font-family

How do I change the font and font size in dash to panel?

[image: The big, ugly fonts in dash to panel]

Comment: can you attach a full picture of PrintScreen and not the cropped pic.

Comment: Although I posted an answer, I found in fact that it fully answers your question, so your question may be marked as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *Dash to Panel* Gnome Shell extension simply adheres to the style defined in the Gnome Shell theme in use. Therefore, the extension does not offer options to customize appearance. To change the appearance, you can try finding another Gnome Shell theme that suits your taste. If however you want fine control over just the font settings, then the only way would be to edit the style sheet of your Gnome Shell theme directly. These style sheets use the same syntax as these used for web pages. See [this Ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/963667/how-can-i-change-the-font-of-the-top-bar-without-changing-the-shell-theme/963686#963686) to learn how you could find and edit the appropriate style files.