# How do I change font size on top bar?

Tags: 18.04, themes, fonts, gnome-shell

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 with GNOME desktop.

Please advise which will be the easy way to increase the top bar size as well as font size.

Answer (score 0):

Font size of the top bar is set by your GNOME Shell theme. The default GNOME Shell theme of Ubuntu 18.04 is dictated by the `ubuntu.css` file in your `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/` directory.

After opening the `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css` file you should find a `stage` section near the top, which would look something like the following:

```
stage {
  font-family: <font-to-display>;
  font-size: <size-of-the-displayed-font>;
  color: <colour-of-the-displayed-font>; }
```

Change the value for `font-size` and save the file (note that you'll need root privilege to edit this system file). This would change the font-size of various components of GNOME Shell including the top bar in a consistent manner. You need to reboot or relogin or restart GNOME Shell to see the effect.

---

**Note:** It's not generally advisable to edit a system file, especially without backing it up. You can alternatively override your GNOME Shell theme from your local directory, refer to [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/963686/480481).

Comment: Hi.. I noted your comment.. I think your answer changes lot of things along with the top bar..

Comment: @PRATAP That's true, this changes font-size of various components of the shell in a synchronised manner for the sake of consistency instead of just changing the font-size of the top bar. What I meant was the answer you posted to the other question was for a custom GNOME shell theme installed locally in `~/.themes/`, whereas this one is presumably (as OP didn't mention anything otherwise) asking for a way to do that for a standard installation of Ubuntu 18.04. So I believe this question has a greater appeal and it would be better if you could post an answer here adapting the older answer.

Comment: Also please feel free to edit my answer if you prefer that instead.