# Changing the color of the desktop icon's text in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: 22.04, customization

As the title says, I'd like to change the color of the text of the icons in the desktop, since by default the text is white and since my background image is white/blue-ish, it's pretty hard to read.
I've tried doing this: [How do I change the color of desktop icon text](https://askubuntu.com/questions/426268/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-desktop-icon-text) but after rebooting it doesn't seem to work. Any help or resources would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New Ubuntu now uses `gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons-ng`. Let's change the preferences inside that:

1. Run `gnome-extensions prefs ding@rastersoft.com` in terminal

[image: ding preferences]

2. Enable "Use dark text in icon labels"

[image: using dark text in icon labels]